# JBoss_4_0_3_SP1 ROOT.war is coming from wrong path

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss and as far as i know ROOT.war folder location should be this

`'/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/deploy/uuid-key-generator.sar/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war'`

but in my server path is this

```
'/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/deploy/uuid-key-generator.sar/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war'
```

I tried to delete jboss-web.deployer folder from this folder uuid-key-generator.sar and try to access link `http://localhost:8080/index.html`,

I am getting 404 error in browser.

index.html is present in this folder

`'/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/deploy/uuid-key-generator.sar/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/index.html'`.

Can anyone please help me, how can I correct or change path ?

Comment: Look at the console log. Does ROOT.war get deploy correctly without errors? Is 8080 the correct port?

Comment: yes ROOT.war deployed correctly and port is 8080

Comment: hmm - as I understand it, ROOT.war should be expanded into tmp and work folders within the Jboss's deployment folder. Maybe be try delete these 2 folders and restart JBoss. The next thing would be to upload your JBoss console log for inspection. BTW, all the paths mentioned above looks identical. Another thing to try is to rename ROOT.war to another name just incase ROOT "/" has conflict with another .war which registered the "/" context.